# Iptables: How to redirect all 8443 incoming and outgoing to 443

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

So I understand that you need to allow the connection first (right?)

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Then you need to set up the redirect (right?)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

Then also allow the outgoing response from 8443 go to 443 (right?)

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

My scenario: I have an application server locally using 8443 but I want all traffic to connect using standard ports. I'm having problems with services that use my secure http port

```
ie. https://mywebsite.com   **NOT**  https://mywebsite.com/8443
```

**Problem: I'm not sure my rules to iptalbes are correct**

Comment: `--to-porr` is a typo? You don't need the OUTPUT REDIRECT rule, or the `--dport 443` ACCEPT in the INPUT chain (by the time the traffic hits INPUT it is destined for 8443, not 443).

Comment: @fukawi2 Yeah good catch (on the typo). So if if simply want to redirect all incoming 443 traffic to my webapps 8443 port; what are the least amount of rules/bare essential rules that i need to add to my iptables. Much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mangle - mark all incoming packets with dport 443 (second iptables chain)

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x64/0xffffffff
```

nat - change destination port for market packets (third iptables chain)

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m mark --mark 0x64 -j DNAT --to-destination :8443
```

filter - accept marked packet with new dport (fifth iptables chain)

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8443 -m mark --mark 0x64 -j ACCEPT
```

on older systems use `-m state --state` instead of `-m conntrack --ctstate`:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8443 -m mark --mark 0x64 -j ACCEPT
```

This is most efficient way, this is how RH utilities do it by default for local redirects.

[image]

Comment: whoa. I greatly appreciate the response. But so I'm not blindly using this answer to solve my question, can you add some explanation for what nat, mangle and filter. Much much thanks in advance

Comment: answer updated accordingly

Comment: So what is/where is the first iptable chain - as seen you started with 'second'

Comment: Picture added. As you can see - all these rules are before local processing.

Comment: -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8443 -m mark --mark 0x64 -j ACCEPT               This returns "No chain/target match by that name"

Comment: distro? iptables -L please

Comment: centos iptables v1.4.7

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Put these in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

Comment: try `-m state --state` instead of `-m conntrack --ctstate`

Comment: You're welcome, ctstate is introduced in newer systems and --state is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

We are doing something similar for an app running in tomcat. Not sure about the OUTPUT statement. We don't use that... Also... Your nat PREROUTING statement has a typo?

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Sep 19 12:31:52 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [623016:133354762]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8044 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Sep 19 12:31:52 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Sep 19 12:31:52 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [116:5915]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2533:132017]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [87137:6439722]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [87137:6439722]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Sep 19 12:31:52 2013
```